# The private key was in an unrecognized format while updating the SSL on AWS

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, ssl-certificate, pem, godaddy-api

I have a GoDaddy SSL certificate and I have to update my SSL on AWS EC2. I got three files from GoDaddy.

1. somenumber.crt
2. somenuber.pem
3. gd_bundle-g2-g1.crt

I am trying to update all three files from the admin panel but I am getting the error on PEM file

> Private key was in an unrecognized format.

Screenshot of the image

[image]

Comment: You are putting a certificate in the box for privatekey. A certificate is not a privatekey. A privatekey is a privatekey. You should have saved your privatekey when (or possibly before) you created the CSR. See https://www.godaddy.com/help/request-my-ssl-certificate-562 and https://www.godaddy.com/help/manually-install-an-ssl-certificate-on-my-aws-server-32075

Comment: @dave_thompson_085, I am also following second link which you shared. I am getting the issue in point number 8.

Comment: I downloaded SSL file from GoDaddy then I rename the file extension from crt to txt file to get my code and pasted in the field.